# How to use curl to download a raw file in a git repository from Git hosting site?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to get a file from Git repository. I am following the examples in this link:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository

However, the above link is for GitLab, and I need to do this for a file on GitHub.

So using Postman and my personal access token, I am invoking the following API link:
"https://github.com/xxxxxx/blob/master/abc-def/loginservicedapr-hpa.yaml?ref=master"

But I am getting a big html file as response, my actual file content is embedded in the html body. I have also tried invoking the following url:
"https://github.com/xxxxxx/blob/master/abc-def/loginservicedapr-hpa.yaml/raw?ref=master"

But it is giving the same response. Please help.

Comment: Gitlab or github?

Comment: github-removed the tag-my bad for the mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Github you can do:

```
curl \                                                                               
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}\?ref\=<ref, e.g. master>
```

For example, to get a file from the Laravel public repository:

```
curl \                                                                               
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/contents/.styleci.yml\?ref\=79fb6af96ebf0325cef15c3132157fdf75f6fd6c
```

[Github Docs for getting repository content](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content) and [custom media types](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#custom-media-types).